# Prove that the set of limit points of a function is all $R$

Tags: real-analysis

> How do I prove that the function
>   $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ has as limit points on $0$ the entire real line?

I know that I should get a sequence $x_n$ for each real $y$ such that $x_n\rightarrow 0$  and $f(x_n)\rightarrow y$. How can I prove this?

Comment: A limit cannot be whole real line. I bet you need to restate what you want to prove.

Comment: Limit point and limit are not the same concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any real number $a$ the equation
$$
\frac{1}{x}\,\sin\frac{1}{x}=a
$$
has infinite solutions that converge to $0$.

Comment: How do I have that result? Obviously my doubt follow from what you said, but this is a result that I don't know how to prove.

Comment: How is the grapf of $(\sin(1/x))/x$? Since $\sin$ oscilates between $\pm1$, it oscilates between $\pm1/x$, and the oscilations are faster as $x\to0$. This means that the horizontal line $y=a$ cuts the graph in a sequence of points that have $0$ as a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The graph of $y=\sin \frac1x$ has every point in $0\times[-1,1]$ as a limit point. Now what does applying the factor $\frac1x$ do to this graph in the vicinity of $0$?